SMS/MMS Backup with offline search
Over many years, I have established a cumulative backup of all text messages. I have used various utilities with root over the years: Titanium Backup, SMS Backup Restore, Swift, etc. My final zipped backup is now several gigabytes in size.
When I factory reset or switch to a new phone, I save the entire backup to a file then restore the entire backup. After copying the file back to the phone, the backup app now takes 45 minutes to restore. Then, the phone takes 8+ hours to process the conversations. I know the process is done when the conversation counts stop growing.
I wouldn't need to keep restoring this gigantic backup on my phone, if I could easily search the conversations and media offline.
How can I view and search my SMS/MMS backup offline? Do any utilities offer a way to view conversations and media other than restoring back to a phone?

Backups made by SMS Backup and restore can be viewed in browser // I don't use MMS so can't comment on it

Also from within the app as answered here

The part of your question asking for utilities will be deemed off-topic here, but is on-topic at Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

I have a possible answer, but to help me write it, I'm wondering how your existing SMS/MMS program allows you to search the media files.  How does it do that?
